# Using if else statement in Python Parser of Field Calculator in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I need help in writing the python script in the field calculator. I have three fields namely:
CODE
COMPLEX
Map1

Map1 is an empty field that I want to populate. I have a number of conditions to cater with in a single Map1 field. e.g. If CODE is 1.1.7 and COMPLEX is 4 then the output for Map1 should be 1.3, and these conditions continue with different CODE and COMPLEX values. I have been trying to write it like this but it doesn't work:

Parser
Python

Code Block

```
def Reclass( !CODE! , !COMPLEX! ):
    if ( !CODE! == 1.1.7 and !COMPLEX! == 4):
        return 1.3
    elif ( !CODE! == 3.2.0 and !COMPLEX! == 4):
        return 1.3    
    else:
        return 0
```

Map1 =

```
Reclass( !CODE! , !COMPLEX! )
```

Can anyone tell me where I am making a mistake? Or any other way of doing it?

Comment: The fields in the code block are just variables, no exclamation marks. it should be *def Reclass(my_code,my_complex)* or something like that. The calling of it in the field box is correct.

Comment: Thanks Michael for a quick reply. I've edited the code block with no exclamation marks now, but I'm still getting an  error. I am new to programming and probably making a simple mistake somewhere :( that I don't know of: Now its like this: def Reclass( my_code,my_complex):
    if (my_code == 1.1.7 and my_complex == 4):
        return 1.3
    elif (my_code == 3.2.0 and my_complex == 4):
        return 1.3 
    else:
        return 0

Comment: It's always best to edit your question rather than trying to include code in comments - your formatting options there are far superior.  This Meta [answer](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) may help with framing and interacting on your questions.

Comment: PolyGeo's answer is correct, copy that into your code block and you should be fine. If you're still having problems edit/update your question with the current code block either as text or alt+PrtScn and paste the field calculator dialog. Please ensure that you've selected the python language radio button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your code block.

Instead of:

```
def Reclass( !CODE! , !COMPLEX! ):
    if ( !CODE! == 1.1.7 and !COMPLEX! == 4):
        return 1.3
    elif ( !CODE! == 3.2.0 and !COMPLEX! == 4):
        return 1.3    
    else:
        return 0
```

try:

```
def Reclass( CODE , COMPLEX ):
    if ( CODE == "1.1.7" and COMPLEX == 4):
        return 1.3
    elif ( CODE == "3.2.0" and COMPLEX == 4):
        return 1.3    
    else:
        return 0
```

The exclamation marks are needed in your expression because there they are indicating field names but in the code block `CODE` and `COMPLEX` are Python variables and could be called `a` and `b` if you wanted.

The other problem is that your CODE field appears to be of type text so I have added quotes around the tests of its values.  I cannot tell if your Map1 and COMPLEX fields are text or numbers so I have not put them there - you may need to!

Comment: That's it! See example on this page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002m000000

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael. Removing the exclamation and changing the data type from Number to String, followed by quoting e.g. '1.1.7' helped. Thanks again :)